# Обновление UI у клиента

Tags: c#, unity3d

При попадании по игроку нужно обновлять показания его здоровья **на его стороне**. Почему этого не происходит и как правильно это реализовать?

При попадании по игроку

```
[Command]
private void CmdPlayerShot(string playerId,int damage)
{
    Player player = GameManager.GetPlayerById(playerId);
    player.MakeDamage(damage);
}
```

Нанесение урона в классе Player

```
public void MakeDamage(int damage)
{
    currentHp -= damage;
    CanvasUpdate();
    ...    
}
```

Обновление показателей в классе Player

```
public void CanvasUpdate()
{
    canvas.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = (currentHp < 0 ? 0 : currentHp).ToString();        
}
```

Comment: Вы просмотрели всю цепочку? Ошибки не вываливаются? canvas.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>() - это плохо. Задайте текстовый компонент как - переменную, и используйте её

Answer (score 0):

Могу вам посоветовать пройти официальный обучающий курс от *Unity*, который посвящен мультиплееру с использованием их платформы. Там есть уроки посвящённые, в том числе, и созданию полоски HP. Он короткий и везде есть примеры кода и пояснение зачем это нужно.

Если английского не хватает, то там может помочь и банальный гугл переводчик, благо ничего сложного там не используется.

[Официальная серия уроков](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking)
[Урок по HP в одиночной игре](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/player-health-single-player?playlist=29690)
[Перевод HP на мультиплеерную основу](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/networking-player-health?playlist=29690)

Если коротко, то вы в своём коде изменяете HP только у сущности игрока, которая находится на сервере. Сама переменная, как я понимаю, синхронизируемой не помечена и как следствие её изменение не отражается на остальных игроках. Посмотрите внимательно на использование класса *[NetworkBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.html)* и атрибута *[SyncVar](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html)*.

При этом синтаксис типа: *[[SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute-hook.html)*, позволяет вызывать конкретный метод при изменении синхронизируемой переменной (в вашем случае логичным будет вызывать CanvasUpdate).

Comment: Переменная помечена SyncVar, она изменяется у игроков

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, хук используете?

Comment: Нет, но метод и без него вызывается, судя по брэкпоинтам